# Add metadata onan existing HKWorkout

Tags: ios, healthkit, hkhealthstore

Is it possible to add metadata on existing HKWorkout (subclass of HKObject with the metadata property) ?

If not any idea on how to add data from my app to existing workout record in healthkitstore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Records in HealthKit are immutable. To add metadata to an existing record, you would need to delete the existing record and save a new one with modified metadata. Note your app can only delete a record that it previously saved. If your goal is to be able to modify *any* workout saved in HealthKit, I’m afraid that’s not possible.